Custom Event does not propagate wxWidgets C++
I created a custom event to pass Card class in the event :
#include "card.hpp"

class CardEvent: public wxEvent
{
public:
    CardEvent(wxEventType eventType, int winid, const Card &carddata)
        : wxEvent(winid, eventType),
          m_card(carddata)
    {
    }
 
    // accessors
    Card GetCard() const { return m_card; }

    // implement the base class pure virtual
    virtual wxEvent *Clone() const { return new CardEvent(*this); }
 
private:
    const Card m_card;
};

wxDECLARE_EVENT(EVT_CARDADDED, CardEvent);

Defined in my MainWindow :
wxDEFINE_EVENT(EVT_CARDADDED, CardEvent);

And used to bind the event in MainWindow :
this->Bind(EVT_CARDADDED, &MainWindow::OnCardAdded, this);

I send the event on another class (wxPanel):
void BlockCardPanel::OnClickAddCard(wxCommandEvent &evt){
    Card card(-1, "New Card");
    ShowCardDialog *dialog = new ShowCardDialog(this, card);
    
    if (dialog->ShowModal() == wxOK){
        CardPanel *cardpanel = new CardPanel(this);
        card.SetId(cardpanel->GetId());
        cardpanel->SetTitle(card.GetTitle());
        // ...  I fill the view 
    }

    CardEvent cevt(EVT_CARDADDED, this->GetId(), card);
    cevt.SetEventObject(this);
    ProcessEvent(cevt);
}


But the event does not reach MainWindow.
I tried calling:
ProcessWindowEvent(cevt);

and
this->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(cevt);


Events don't propagate to their parent window by default, this only happens for wxCommandEvents, so the simplest way to fix your issue is to derive your CardEvent from wxCommandEvent and not wxEvent directly. This may also make sense, if "card added" is a kind of "command", i.e. the handler will actually add a card in response to getting this event.
If not, i.e. if it's a notification, then you might prefer to keep wxEvent as the base class but do m_propagationLevel = wxEVENT_PROPAGATE_MAX; in your event class ctor: this will set up the event to be propagated upwards.

Hi, VZ. Thank you very much. I used the wxCommandEvent. As you said i wanted to pass the card to be created in the main window by a service, that way i can have all the events handle in one place, instead of passing the service everywhere.
